# Stopping text from splitting to multiple lines on the periods in web addresses

Tags: android, unicode, textview, word-wrap

I have an Android TextView displaying some text, and it's multi-line.  However, in the text, I sometimes have domain names; how can I stop the TextView from splitting the lines up on the periods in them?

Is there a unicode non-breaking-period, for example?

---

To see the issue in action in wrapping an email address, run
`android create project --target 16 --path demo --package com.example.demo --activity MainActivity`
and change the text in `res/layout/main.xml` to "`Hello World, MyActivity filler text + email foo@foo.com`".  That produces this output on a Galaxy S3 (API level 16):

[image: Email wrapping]

(Adjust text as appropriate to see wrapping on devices with other screen sizes.  Notably, the wrapping is done correctly in Intellij's layout preview, it's only on the device that it's faulty.)

Comment: @blahdiblah, what's your target SDK version? I can't reproduce this problem on Nexus 4 (API level 18).

Comment: @shoerat I'm seeing this on a few devices running <18 (e.g., a Galaxy Nexus running 16).  I'll try and scrounge up an 18 device and see if it's a problem there too.  Of course I'd like a solution for earlier API levels too, it's not as if these devices are ancient.

Comment: @blahdiblah, mind to put some code? Maybe that's an implementation dependent issue?

Comment: @blahdiblah are your email addresses mailto: prefixed?  Are they hyperlinked?

Comment: @blahdiblah I see TextView has a setAutoLinkMask and if you look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#ALL you can see you can set it to linkify email addresses.  On the other hand, back when I had the problem, I didn't want the addresses to be clickable...  I don't recall if I ever solved the problem.

Comment: @Will See included code.  Addresses are just plain text, no `mailto:`, not clickable, nor is either of those features desired.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TLDR;**

@Matt McMinn has already shown a solution for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14422947/1893766), go grab it. I am only re-iterating that solution here.

---

Note that, this issue has already been fixed at platform level in Android 4.2.2. See the below screenshots for word wrap comparison for the same code base but different platform versions on Galaxy Nexus.

[image: Word wrap comparison on Android 4.1.2 vs Android 4.2.2]

Hence, if you are not targeting older versions of Android, you may not wish to use this fix at all.

### The code

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.nobr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.BufferType;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView helloWorld = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
        helloWorld.setText(R.string.hello_world, BufferType.EDITABLE);

        TextView longText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.long_text);
        longText.setText(R.string.long_text_with_url, BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <com.example.nobr.NonBreakingPeriodTextView
        android:id="@+id/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.example.nobr.NonBreakingPeriodTextView
        android:id="@+id/long_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hello_world"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hello_world"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**NonBreakingPeriodTextView.java**:

```
package com.example.nobr;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NonBreakingPeriodTextView extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "NonBreakingPeriodTextView";

    public NonBreakingPeriodTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonBreakingPeriodTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        Editable editable = getEditableText();
        if (editable == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "non-editable text");
            return;
        }
        int width = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        if (width == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "zero-length text");
            return;
        }

        Paint p = getPaint();
        float[] widths = new float[editable.length()];
        p.getTextWidths(editable.toString(), widths);
        float curWidth = 0.0f;
        int lastWSPos = -1;
        int strPos = 0;
        final char newLine = '\n';
        final String newLineStr = "\n";
        boolean reset = false;
        int insertCount = 0;

        /*
         * Traverse the string from the start position, adding each character's width to the total
         * until: 1) A whitespace character is found. In this case, mark the whitespace position. If
         * the width goes over the max, this is where the newline will be inserted. 2) A newline
         * character is found. This resets the curWidth counter. curWidth > width. Replace the
         * whitespace with a newline and reset the counter.
         */

        while (strPos < editable.length()) {
            curWidth += widths[strPos];

            char curChar = editable.charAt(strPos);

            if (curChar == newLine) {
                reset = true;
            } else if (Character.isWhitespace(curChar)) {
                lastWSPos = strPos;
            } else if (curWidth > width && lastWSPos >= 0) {
                editable.replace(lastWSPos, lastWSPos + 1, newLineStr);
                insertCount++;
                strPos = lastWSPos;
                lastWSPos = -1;
                reset = true;
            }

            if (reset) {
                curWidth = 0.0f;
                reset = false;
            }

            strPos++;
        }

        if (insertCount != 0) {
            setText(editable);
        }
    }
}
```

### The result

**On Android 4.1.2 (Galaxy Nexus)**

[image: Word wrap on Android 4.1.2 with the fix]

**On Android 2.3.3 (AVD, Nexus One clone)**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: BTW, tested the above fix on Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1.1) and it works there too.

Comment: Very nicely prepared and explained answer!  Does this work on very old versions of Android too?

Comment: The text isn't editable when I do this so the first if statement always returns false? Ideas?

Comment: @MattWolfe, are you using the correct `BufferType`? What target device, API level are you testing against?

Comment: Ahh, somehow I missed that part of the code above! Thanks.

Comment: When android restores your views upon returning from another activity this doesn't work. For whatever reason onSizeChanged doesn't fire and the original text you placed will be present. Not sure how to fix this yet.

Answer (score 1):

To tell android to parse the domain links in the TextView use this code in the TextView code block:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

This will show the domain names as links in the app and wont split the lines.

Comment: thats very useful to know; but is there also a way to avoid them being split *without* turning them into hyperlinks?  (The domain my context is shown as part of instructions for the user to carry out on a PC...)

Comment: could you post the code that you are using currently? I can suggest better with an idea of what you have done so far.

Comment: I have actually seen it split lines with android:autoLink="web" on a Honeycomb device; the text "www.andromo.com" at the end of a long sentence was split at the "www." part.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

android:singleLine="true" in xml

Answer (score 0):

for me didn't work solution of @ozbek respectively @Matt McMinn, I had to change line

```
else if(Character.isWhitespace(curChar))
```

for

```
} else if (curChar == '\u00A0') {
```

but otherwise great solution, thanks