# Don't wrap text in Android TextView at period in abbreviation

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

Is there a way to control where a TextView chooses to wrap its text?  The issue that I'm having is that it wants to wrap at periods - so a string like "Available in the U.S. and Canada" could wrap after the period between the U and the S.  Is there a way to tell the TextView not to wrap unless there's a period and a space, or some programmatic way to control the wrapping?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up writing my own algorithm to break the text only on whitespace.  I had originally used the [breakText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#breakText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20float,%20float[])) method of [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html), but was having some issues (that may actually be resolved in this version of the code, but that's OK).  This isn't my best chunk of code, and it could definitely be cleaned up a bit, but it works.  Since I'm overriding [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), I just call this from the [onSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method to ensure that there's a valid width.

```js
private static void breakManually(TextView tv, Editable editable)
{
    int width = tv.getWidth() - tv.getPaddingLeft() - tv.getPaddingRight();
    if(width == 0)
    {
        // Can't break with a width of 0.
        return false;
    }

    Paint p = tv.getPaint();
    float[] widths = new float[editable.length()];
    p.getTextWidths(editable.toString(), widths);
    float curWidth = 0.0f;
    int lastWSPos = -1;
    int strPos = 0;
    final char newLine = '\n';
    final String newLineStr = "\n";
    boolean reset = false;
    int insertCount = 0;

    //Traverse the string from the start position, adding each character's
    //width to the total until:
    //* A whitespace character is found.  In this case, mark the whitespace
    //position.  If the width goes over the max, this is where the newline
    //will be inserted.
    //* A newline character is found.  This resets the curWidth counter.
    //* curWidth > width.  Replace the whitespace with a newline and reset 
    //the counter.

    while(strPos < editable.length())
    {
        curWidth += widths[strPos];

        char curChar = editable.charAt(strPos);

        if(((int) curChar) == ((int) newLine))
        {
            reset = true;
        }
        else if(Character.isWhitespace(curChar))
        {
            lastWSPos = strPos;
        }
        else if(curWidth > width && lastWSPos >= 0)
        {
            editable.replace(lastWSPos, lastWSPos + 1, newLineStr);
            insertCount++;
            strPos = lastWSPos;
            lastWSPos = -1;
            reset = true;
        }

        if(reset)
        {
            curWidth = 0.0f;
            reset = false;
        }

        strPos++;
    }

    if(insertCount != 0)
    {
         tv.setText(editable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, this worked beautifully for me! I just had to modify it a bit - I needed custom wrapping behavior for my custom dialog, where a TextView didn't give me its correct size. No worries - just used my dialog's width minus the TextView's paddings, since it's set to MATCH_PARENT anyways.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Also did a little modifying, because I only need 1 line break, so it would break at the current strPos when no whitespace was found yet.

Answer (score -1):

There is a spannable called WrapTogetherSpan.  There's no documentation on it, but it sounds like text inside one shouldn't wrap.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work; the spans were being added, but the breaks were still occurring mid-span.  The one or two other instances I've seen online of people trying this haven't led to success either.