# Prevent word wrapping on certain words (domain name) in android

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

I have a view that says something like: "Register with mysite.com for free"

The text should wrap if needed, which it currently does, but I don't want it to wrap at mysite.com like so:

> Register with mysite.
>
> com for free

Is there anyway to prevent the system from wrapping on the period?

Comment: can you provide the xml of your TextView?

Comment: Technically it's a button but it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: I want it to wrap I just don't want it to break on a certain word.. I just did some more googling and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373157/dont-wrap-text-in-android-textview-at-period-in-abbreviation
Looks like basically the same question but the answers aren't very satisfactory.

Comment: I find the answer you mentioned very good. I don't think you'll find an easier solution than doing the wrapping yourself and that answer provides exactly that.

Comment: Try: android:singleLine="true"

Comment: I don't want all the text on 1 line, I just don't want it to wrap at the period as mysite.com should be on the same line.