# TextView line wrapping on punctuation

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm got a layout that contains a multi-line TextView. This text view sometimes ends with "..." In some situations "..." is wrapped incorrectly.

For example, the string: "Retrieving Something Detail..." gets wrapped as:

```
Retrieving Something Detail..
.
```

This looks ugly, what I need is:

```
Retrieving Something
Detail...
```

It is not as simple as inserting a "\n" into the string, because this is a general component that can display arbitrary strings.

Here is the layout that I'm using (the text is just there as an example, it is usually set dynamically using .setText()):

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"    
    android:padding="15dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/progressStyle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loading_text"
        android:text="Retrieving Something Detail..."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What can I do to make it wrap correctly (i.e. wrap on spaces only, not on individual characters).

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373157/dont-wrap-text-in-android-textview-at-period-in-abbreviation/14422947#14422947

Comment: Why don't you replace "..." (3 dot characters) with "\u2026" (single ellipsis character)?

Comment: Late response, but thank you both, both solutions work. I'm going for the "\u2026" as that is a bit simpler.