# Java preferred line break in a String

Tags: java, android, string, line-breaks

I have a String like this:

```
"speed1: 10 km/h, speed2: 20 km/h, speed3: 30 km/h, speed4: 40 km/h, speed5: 50 km/h"
```

I want to display this string in a TextView, which can have a variable width.
On some devices, the hole String fits in one line. On other devices, 2-3 lines are needed.

I want the String to be broken only at the comma- characters, so that parameters and values are on the same line.

Is there a special character in Android for that?
(Or do I have to first let the String be drawn, count the number of lines, and then replace some commas by a newline character).

Comment: Change textview's property to multilines

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373157/dont-wrap-text-in-android-textview-at-period-in-abbreviation

Answer (score 2):

Maybe ugliest solution in world, but how about replacing the "normal" spaces except the ones after comma, with Unicode non-breaking space? ("\u00A0")?