# How do I keep a certain group of words together in a textview without breaking?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have some text in a textview with a link at the end that says "click to visit site". I'd like this link to stay together (not break over a line) even if it means going onto a new line.

strings.xml code is basically:

```
<string name="text_string">Blah blah blah very long line of text. <a href="link">Click to visit site</a></string>
```

and my textview is:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@string/text_string" />
```

What happens is that sometimes the "Click to visit site" gets split over a line break, but I'd like that entire phrase to stay together. However, I don't want to force it to be its own line if it fits all together on the previous line. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Don't wrap text in Android TextView at period in abbreviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373157/dont-wrap-text-in-android-textview-at-period-in-abbreviation)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to replace spaces with non-break character spaces `\u00A0` anywhere I didn't want the split to happen.