# How to stop a textview to split the words?

Tags: android, textview

I have a android `textview` and I am setting text

```
String htmlAsString="That is great I will request one of our advisor to contact you to provide details on the camp availability";    
Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlAsString.replace(" ", "&#160") );
textview.setText(htmlAsSpanned);
```

At the time of running. I am getting like below

[image]

I don't want split my text.How I can stop to splitting of the word

Comment: set maxLines to 1

Comment: I can't set because it have more lines. I want to show all with multi line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Comment: obviosuly you shouldn't use &#160... using &#160(non breaking space) makes your sentence one word ... if you would use "normal space" it will break on them(spaces) when needed

Comment: By the way, what's the need of HTML? Normal text would be fine.

Comment: @Krishna did you tried with Spannable TextView ?

Comment: @NoiseGenerator I am receiving the text from server not my local string

Comment: may be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/19451256/4571931